# My render is coming out buggy

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, hdri

Good night, I'm a beginner in Blender and I finished my first render in it, but when rendering in the cloud farm (my laptop doesn't have the hardware to render) Super Renders and in Turbo Render, the final image is as shown in the first attachment.

While in Shading view it is correct, view in attachment 2.

Initially, I thought it was a bug that would happen if the HDR image had not been attached to the file, but in the Shading display the lack of it is shown in attachment 3.

Attachment 1:
[image]

Attachment 2:
[image]

Attachment 3:
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with render farms but the HDR image is not packed into the blend file and it's an external file. This is shown by the folder icon of the *Image Texture* node in screenshot 2. Now the question is, have you packed and sent the HDRI to the render farm manually? In a ZIP file for example? Is the file path correct? In case of doubt, you can tell Blender to pack all images into the blend file. Use the main menu entry *File > External Data > Pack Resources* for this and save the blend file. The file size should increase.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't think that's it, the render farm can recreate the file and add the external files, in the case of HDRI.

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your world shader:

[image: world shader]

You should remove the three highlighted nodes.  The third one is hiding behind the mapping node on the left, and you'll have to move the mapping node to remove it.

The problem that's confusing cycles is that you have an image texture with no image connected to the volume input of the *World Output* node.

When you're done your world shader should look like this:

[image: Corrected world shader]

With that change, and setting the Render device to *GPU Compute*, this renders rather quickly on my laptop: (Shown at a reduced side to fit a StackExchange limit)

[image: Shown at a reduced side to fit a StackExchange limit]